# Assigning values to multiple variables from a list

Tags: replacement, assignment

I have  a solution of the following form:

$F(x)= \\
\qquad c+(x_0+x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_n)- \\
\qquad (x_0\,\log(x_0+\sqrt{x_0})+x_1\,\log(x_1+\sqrt{x_1})+x_2\,\log(x_2+\sqrt{x_2})+\ldots +x_n\,\log(x_n+\sqrt{x_n}))$

I want to replace $x_0\ldots x_n$ from an array containing $x_0\ldots x_n$ as $x=\{x_0,x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n\}$

How this can be done in Mathematica?

Is there a direct Mathematica solution like `Replace` ( `/.` ) to this problem?

Comment: Is there anything after $log$ as a parameter?

Comment: For `n=3`, lease post the actual expression for the "solution" and an example `x` along with the desired answer.

Comment: @bcegkmqs23 yes there is. 
Full solution for n = 3 looks like this:
$F(x)=c+x_3-x_3*log(x_3+sqrt(x_3))$

Comment: and lets assume $x_3=0.0009$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your `F` contains indexed variables `x[0], x[1], ...`. You just need to make replacement rules:

```
xList = RandomReal[10, 10];
rules = Thread[Array[x, 10, 0] -> xList]
```

> `{x[0] -> 7.30088, x[1] -> 6.64534, x[2] -> 0.195005, x[3] -> 0.750164,
>     x[4] -> 1.75732, x[5] -> 8.85201, x[6] -> 2.86472, x[7] -> 6.51873, 
>    x[8] -> 2.91673, x[9] -> 7.25998}`

and use them as `F /. rules`.

Comment: You can skip `[#]&`.

Comment: @Kuba, yes, I edited my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there something you need listed below?

```
g = # - # Log[# + Sqrt@#] &;
f[x_List,] := c + Total[g /@ x]
f@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

```
g = # - # Log[# + Sqrt@#] &;
f = c + Total[g /@ Table[x[i], {i, 5}]];
With[{x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[#]] &}, f]
```

Comment: $g$ in my case is already stored in the form described above. $c$ also doesn't matter. Only thing i want to do is assign values to $x_i$ from x wherever they appear in $g$. Apparently above two suggestion doesn't seem to work for me. First one gives the "SetDelayed::write" and second one appends $x$ to $g$, $i$ times.